# Count the number of null values using pandas framework

Tags: python, pandas

Write python code to find the total number of null values on the excel file without using isnull function ( you should use loop statement)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using for statement in dataframes is not a good practice. If you're doing only for challenge, this could help:

```
data = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
data.fillna(False, inplace=True)

amount_nan = 0
for column in data:
    for value in data[column]:
        if not value:
            amount_nan = amount_nan + 1

print(amount_nan)
```